# Attribute authorisation in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following class in my `Models` folder

```
namespace School.Models
{
        public enum Grade
        {
            A, B, C, D, F
        }

        public class Enrollment
        {
            public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
            public int CourseID { get; set; }
            public int StudentID { get; set; }
            public Grade Grade { get; set; }

            public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
            public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        }
}
```

I want to make authorisation in the Grade attribute so when a Admin Role log in the Admin can modify the grade value and when a User Role log in, the User can not modify the attribute and only see the value of the grade (and how do I make a default value for the grade attribute)

Comment: authorize the action method ... ask a specific question and not too many

Answer (score 0):

Add the authorize attribute over the controller action that updates the grade.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user or group")]
    public IActionResult UpdateGrade()
    {
        //update grade  here

        return View();
    }
```

Set the default grade in the class constructor.

```
public class Enrollment
{

    public Enrollment()
    {
        Grade = Grade.B;
    }

    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```